# 80's alien movie: young boy finds and protects a glowing alien green rock which becomes his friend

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I've been trying to remember the name of this movie that I watched when I was really young. It's a kids movie about a young boy who finds a green rock/stone, which is an alien, and then has to run from the bad guys in order to protect his alien/rock friend.

It was a glowing green stone and I think somehow it communicated with the boy and it had some sort of powers.

The only other thing I remember is that the alien leaves in the end and the boy gets really sad.

It's definitely not *E.T.*, I don't think the movie was a huge hit. It's also possible the movie is from the 70's.

Comment: I mean.....that sounds like ET, which, if you were young, isn't unreasonable to think that was what it actually was. Nor is it unreasonable to think that there may have been numerous knockoffs around the same time. More details would be helpful, and welcome

Comment: It's definitely not ET, I don't think the movie was a huge hit. It's also possible the movie is from the 70's. Sorry, I know it's not a lot to go on but it's all I remember. It was a glowing green stone and I think somehow it communicated with the boy and it had some sort of powers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The Magic Crystal" (1986)?

This sounds like the one. You didn't say if it was an Asian film but this one was made in Hong Kong. Here is a plot summary from [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091532/):

> Looking to cash in on the popularity of Steven Spielberg's mega-hits
> E.T. and Raiders of the Lost Ark, Hong Kong schlockmeister Wong Jing
> directs this yarn about Andy who, along with buddies Pin-pin and
> Pancho ventures to Greece to find his long lost friend Shen. They soon
> discover Shen is being tailed both by the KGB and by Interpol after
> discovering some rare gems in an archaeological dig. After a unkindly
> series of events, Andy winds up back in Hong Kong with the stones,
> which, it turns out, is not gems but rather an alien life form.
> Meanwhile Karov, an evil magician, is hell bent on getting his hands
> on the gem/alien no matter what.

Comment: Thank you, that's the one! Looks like a bad mover but I'll watch it again nonetheless for nostalgia's sake.

Comment: Thank you Sue. It looks bad. Watchable, but bad.

Comment: I changed the YouTube link as the former one was dead, but now the second timestamp isn't valid anymore. I'm not willing to watch the whole thing to find it back, so if you have the time to further edit... :)